# Spring Cloud Function with Reactive types (AWS)

Tags: aws-lambda, reactive, spring-cloud-function

I've been trying to find a simple example of Spring Cloud Function with reactive types to work with AWS, but I think the AWS library itself doesn't support reactive types.

Any recommendations on how to extend support for this?

Thanks